# Collection view при нажатии не отрабатывает делегат didSelectItemAt indexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Делегаты прописал, с этим проблем нет.

Вот моя иерархия :

```
- ScrollView
     - FormContainerView (`UIVIew`)
           - CollectionView
           - Other Views
```

Если я меняю иерархию следующим образом, то тап на ячейку срабатывает:

```
- ScrollView
     - CollectionView
     - FormContainerView (`UIVIew`)               
           - Other Views
```

Но такой вариант мне не подходит, так как при скроле `ColelctionView` не скролится.

UI полностью рисуется программно с помощью либы [PinLayout](https://github.com/layoutBox/PinLayout)

Comment: Возможно, FormContainerView перехватывает касания коллекции. Попробуйте `isuserinteractionenabled` выставить в `false`

Comment: @RecursiveDaun не помогает. Еще и блокирует другие тапы своих subview

Comment: Судя по иерархии, возможно, other views перекрывают collectionView и перехватывают нажатия. Без other views работает didSelect?

Answer (score 0):

Снес вот этот код

```
formScrollView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapScrollView)))
```

все работает.